# Which Nuget package for Active Directory should I use?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I built an Azure WebAPI. I **did not create the project with Authentication at the time it was first created**. I added Active directory Authentication based on a code sample from Microsoft. It utilizes Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory which I got from NuGet. It works just fine.

I then created a WebAPI from VS 2017 and selected **Authentication (using AD) at the time of project creation**. It included Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.

I am not sure of the difference between these two NuGet modules nor which is better suited for my Azure WebAPI.

Then comes the modules to use in a .NET WPF client. There is no AuthorizationContext class (and others) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI. Should I stick with Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory in the .NET WPF client or are there equivalents in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI?

Comment: Take a look at this SO post. It covers this topic with good details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590882/microsoft-aspnetcore-vs-microsoft-identitymodel-adal-with-net-core-api-in-azu

Comment: OK. That's helpful. What about for a .NET (say WPF) client? Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI doesn't contain the AuthorizationContext or the PlatformParameters classes. Are there equivalents in  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the WPF related requirement.. I'll check back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For your web api project, answer is it depends on what you're trying to do from within the web api. For most simple scenarios where you just need to read/validate tokens, you should be good with the added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Aurthentication.JwtBearer nuget pacakges. More detailed question/answer available in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590882/microsoft-aspnetcore-vs-microsoft-identitymodel-adal-with-net-core-api-in-azu)
2. In case of your WPF client application although, you won't have much choice. You will need to work with ADAL or MSAL based on which AD version/endpoints you want to use. Also, in case of WPF client more probably than not you will need to acquire a token from Azure AD so internal operations (which library will take care of under the hood e.g. authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync) will be a little more involved than just reading the provided token from a header and hence the package.